# "df" doesn't show all partitions

Tags: partitioning

When using "df -h" the results don't seem to include all partitions on my system.

#### df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            478M     0  478M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M   11M   89M  11% /run
/dev/sda3       5.3G  4.8G  212M  96% /
tmpfs           497M  172K  496M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/lxcfs/controllers
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/0
none            5.3G  4.8G  212M  96% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/11ab67fd7252d090ac0be0dfb799a9800180c8adad17288315218c37386417b9
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/811ed313feca08305bb6bb1e1bdc6b58af7723a2b7f52258d581226f5331c26e/shm
none            5.3G  4.8G  212M  96% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/a5f64c00308cc21e74edc4e2ee14a1c7ec728bd9aa1abc29ffc9d276ac0f9f0d
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/95be412fca6e3e0660ebedb2ca971420bddb02b45fa3150b58176f528c73e310/shm
```

#### lsblk

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   29G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0  9.5M  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0  3.8G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3   8:3    0  5.5G  0 part /
└─sda4   8:4    0 19.7G  0 part  <-------------------- THIS ONE ?
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Why isn't sda4 displayed?

Comment: Type `mount | grep sda4`. If it's empty, so it's not mounted. `dh -h`will not show it

Comment: @Redbob I think this should be an answer

Answer (score 6):

Exec this command to see mounted partitions:

`mount`

Executing 
`mount | grep sda4` will filter to device you want to search for.

If the output of this one is empty, then it's not mounted.

We concluded by this way that `df -h` will show only mounted partitions.

Comment: You don't need to run mount here. The output of `lsblk` will include the mount point if it is mounted and you can see in the output that `sda3` is mounted on `/` but `sda4` has nothing listed for it.

Comment: Exactly, but `mount` gives another view to which devices are really mounted in.

Answer (score 3):

df -h shows only MOUNTED partitions. So mount the partition if you want to see it there.

1. Create mountpoint (this is any direcotry in any location you want)
2. `mount /dev/sda4 /<chosen mountpoint>`
3. `df -h`